How can I replace the operating bar on wooden window blinds?
My window shutters are divided into 4 panels made of wooden slats. Each side has 2 panels and are opened and closed with a vertical piece of cylindrical wood that is attached to each wooden slat allowing them to open and close the shutters.
The wooden cylindrical piece is missing from one panel. Can I replace that cylindrical piece and reattach the wooden slats to it or would I need to replace the entire panel?
For both cases, either replacing the entire panel or the wooden piece, where can I purchase it from?


Google "window interior shutter repair" .  We're not really a shopping site.

The wood piece is just a wood dowel, about a 1/4 inch.  That is the easy part.  Attaching it to the slats is where all the neighbour kids learn new words they should not know yet.

Looks to me like the dowel should have the same U-shaped staples that the slats show, simply stapled perpendicularly.  As crip659 suggests, the trick will be to secure them in place, now that the slats can't be removed.  If you're not too particular about the appearance, I'd suggest getting some wire pieces and bending them into U shapes.  Drill a pair of holes for each in your dowel at the proper spacing for the slats.  Hook a U around each slat's stable and stick the ends of the U into each pair of holes.  Bend the wire back so it doesn't pull out.  Paint white.
If you're particular, you could file a groove in the dowel for the bent back wire to ride in.
Pardon my crappy diagram.


Good ideas. I'd add that a proper hole size would allow the staples to be super-glued or epoxied in, maintaining a factory appearance.

That could work too—the originals were probably just a friction fit.  I just wanted to show some kind of mechanical retention.
